# What languages and libraries should I use to work with Gmail?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, programming-languages, gmail

I want to develop my own web-based tool for searching for messages in the inbox of my Gmail account and deleting some of them.

The projects that I've been working on in my programming life are very different from that one, so my question is: What languages, tools, and libraries should be used for this task?

Comment: I don't think you can do better than Gmail ^^

Comment: I think, gmail is developed by a bunch of people only.

Comment: @Clement Herreman  :I assume you know BetterGMail ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think, you can use [libgmail](http://libgmail.sourceforge.net/)

The `libgmail` project is a pure Python binding to provide access to Google's Gmail web-mail service.

The library currently ships with a demonstration utility to archive messages from a Gmail account into mbox files, suitable for importing into a local email client.

Its free of cost.Download it [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/libgmail/)

Let me know whether it works for you or not.

Comment: Thanks. Does it also allow deleting messages from the inbox?

Comment: Yes,I think so. I suggest it'll better if you read more about it. Because, honestly speaking, I have just a brief idea about it and not more than that.

Answer (score 8):

You ought to be able to do it via a standard IMAP library, which should exist for every language.

Comment: Use an IMAP or POP3 library and then you'll learn skills that you'll be able to take anywhere else.

Comment: optionally ho could do the magic via CURL, but that's pain in the ass with AJAX interfaces like this one

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using gmail filters? There are some easy ways of doing this without resorting to writing full fledged programs [see](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=6579). This may not be as sophisticated as rolling up a custom program but it has served my needs pretty well so far. Also explore Gmail [advanced search](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190) queries. Be forewarned a little ingenuity and creativity is required.

Comment: Thanks. But in this case I want to develop a program.

Comment: Sure why not, I am totally supportive of http://programmer.97things.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Reinvent_the_Wheel_Often